# jdto superclass boolean field binding incorrect value

Tags: jdto

```
public class Model {
}

public class SuperclassDTO {
    private boolean funny = true;

    public boolean isFunny() {
        return funny;
    }

    public boolean setFunny(boolean f) {
        this.funny = f;
    }
}

public class SubclassDTO extends SuperclassDTO {
}


new SubclassDTO().isFunny() //returns true
SubclassDTO dto =  binder.bindFromBusinessObject(SubclassDTO.class, new Model());
dto.isFunny(); //returns false!!!!
```

Isn't this weird? Model class does not have a "funny" field but somehow dto is bind with a wrong value. First I thought jDTO required "getFunny" convention, so it couldn't read the value and just set it "false" but changing the getter name to "getFunny" does not resolve the issue, plus I'm not allowed to modify SuperclassDTO. How can I bind the correct value?

Jdto version 1.4 by the way...

Comment: Which version of jDTO are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're experiencing is a "side effect" of the convention over configuration approach. All the fields on the DTO are configured unless you mark them as transient, either by using the `@DTOTransient` annotation or the `transient` configuration on the XML file. If a configured field does not have a corresponding field on the source bean, it will be set with default values and that is the reason why you're experiencing this behavior.

You have some options to overcome this issue:

- Add the `@DTOTransient` annotation to the DTO.
- Since you're not able to modify the DTO, you could configure it through XML.
- Use Binding lifecycle to Restore the value. By adding code on the subclass.

You might as well submit a bug report on the jDTO issue tracker on github.

Comment: Hmm, making the field transient will cause it not to be bind when it's bind from a different source model too, right? Then I will have to set it manually in those cases. Isn't "if model does not have a getter, leave fields in dto alone" a better default configuration?

Comment: @user1186523 that makes sense as well, if you wish so, please file an issue on the issue tracker and we'll analyze it for future releases.